# generate random string, save it and use it to click on that random name link in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have created a random string `element(by.id('fim-name')).sendKeys(String.random(3));` here random is function used to generate random strin.

I need to save this in some variable(or anything which can be used later) and use that string(name) in some other element as click() function.

Means if the string generated as `test01` than need to search in UI with name `test01` and click on that link.

Answer (score 0):

take the String.random(3) into any var and give a try.

```
var s = String.random(3)
```

Now pass this s in sendkeys,

```
element(by.id('fim-name')).sendKeys(s);
```

Then you can click the element with link,

```
element(by.xpath("//span[text()='" + s + "'])).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const random_text_click = (size) => {

    let charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", ret = '';
    while (size != 0) {
        ret += charset.charAt(Math.random() * charset.length)
        size--;
    }
    element(by.id('----')).sendKeys(ret);
    element(by.xpath(`//*[text()="${ret}"]`)).click();

}
```

This method takes size argument.If you know the exact tag which you want to click may be a button change * in xpath to `//button[text()="${ret}"]`